# How to determine cause of boot halt in Samsung logo screen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot, miui

The apps kept crashing on my phone (even MIUI Home) so I shut it down using the long power press and selecting shut down/power off option.

When I powered it back on, it just stays stuck on the Samsung logo boot screen with the yellow warning sign (which has been there ever since I rooted it).

Here's what I tried which didn't work:

- List item
- cleared cache, dalvik, fixed permissions - FAIL
- with above, it means booting into CWM works fine but booting into OS fails
- reflashed with MIUI i9100 ICS 2.12.14 (still downloading 3.1.25 as I type this) - FAIL
- removed micro SD and SIM and tried booting - FAIL
- earlier today, it started doing the crashing thing too but after reboot, it went into Safe mode. I rebooted again to get out of safe mode. After booting back normally into OS, all my non-system apps were out of there arranged folders and just listed in the next home screens like they were all reinstalled.

So I got to backing up my data with CWM and did a data wipe and it now boots successfully.

I need to restore my data. Can't work with a fresh wipe.

With this, at least I know it's not a HW problem. Or is it? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it always a good thing to have *USB Debugging* on. It can help you check your phone and even recover it if something is wrong.

When your phone is on a boot loop and won't start correctly, you can use *adb* to check where might be the problem. Connect your phone via the USB cable to a PC with adb and then type the following:

```
adb logcat
```

Power your phone and you should see, as your phone starts the boot secuence, a lot of information in the *adb* window. That is the current log of your phone boot secuence (like the one you can see in linux for example). If the phone ends in a boot loop, you should be able to see what is trying to do and then try to fix it.

Comment: It's working fine now. But I will keep this answer in mind when it happens again. Thank you!